# Add hidden values to pictures

Tags: javascript, lightbox, addition

I have a bunch of pictures in a table. The pictures are also used with a lightbox function. 
the simplified code is

```
<table><tr><td>
<a href="images/december122012.jpg" rel="lightbox[group1]" title="December 12, 2012"      value="1" id="december122012" name="december122012"><img src="images/december122012.jpg" width="100px"></a>
<a href="images/december142012.jpg" rel="lightbox[group1]" title="December 14, 2012"      value="1" id="december142012" name="december142012"><img src="images/december142012.jpg" width="100px"></a>
</td></tr></table>
```

what I want to do is have a function that will add the values of the various images. I read the following code to use somewhere but the alert just says undefined.

```
<script>
var val2 = parseInt(december122012.value);
alert (val2.value);
</script>
```

after I get the values to be assigned correctly I'm wanting to do something like

```
var year2012= december122012.value + december142012.value
alert (year2012);
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: `<a>` elements should not have `value` attributes. Use data attributes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.getElementById("december122012").value`.

This will get the value from the "a" elements. The "img" elements do not have a value attribute.

Comment: I did this and it returned "undefined". any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can not just reference an element by a string, you need to use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) or getElementsByName. And when you are reading the attributes, they will be strings so you will have to [convert them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to numbers.